# SQL : Comparing email-addresses in row, and retrieve not found rows

Tags: database, excel, teradata

I am working on a Teradata system in which I have one table(TABLE_NAME), where there is a column of `email_address_table`. I have an excel-sheet in which I have a column of email addresses.

What I am trying to do is, to retrieve all the rows in the table, where the `email_address_table` is not a part of the email addresses present in excel sheet.

As far as I know, `Teradata` cannot directly work with excel sheets, so I am writing code in Java, where I can retrieve the individual email addresses from the column and even format them to a String, which I would like to directly use in the SQL query. So, basically, the query would be shaped in the Java program, based upon the syntax I would require.

Input :

```
    +---------+----------+---------------------------------+
    | id      | name                |          Date        |
    +---------+----------+---------------------------------+
    | 1       | abc@gmail.com       |         21.03.2015   |
    | 2       | def@gmail.com       |          22.04.2015  |
    | 3       | ajk@gmail.com       |          22.03.2015  |
    | 4       | ghi@gmail.com       |          23.03.2015  |
    | 5       | ghi@gmail.com       |          23.03.2015  |
```

Excel sheet :

```
    +---------+-----------+
    |     name            |
    +---------+-----------+
    | abc@gmail.com       |
    | ccc@gmail.com       |
    | ggg@gmail.com       |
    | hhh@gmail.com       |
    | ghi@gmail.com       |
```

Expected query :

```
select * from TABLE_NAME where email_address does not match any in {"email1","email2","email3"...."email-n"}
```

**Also, the TABLE_NAME contains around 80,000 entries, and the excel sheet contains around 4000 email addresses. Any optimal way for this search?**

How can I proceed with this problem. I already have emails from excel sheet as plain string which I can copy paste, change formatting in Java directly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE email_address NOT IN ('email1', 'email2', 'email3')
```

Comment: Thank you for the query. I have already triggered it. Is there a way to optimize this, as the table_name has around 80,000 email addresses and the excel sheet around 4000.

Comment: Does it have to be an excel sheet? If you imported the data into an additional table, you could have `WHERE email_address NOT IN (SELECT email_address FROM additional_table)`.

Comment: The problem is I cannot connect the java program to Teradata directly. I would require an insert query to add in a temporary table the 400 entries.. I already have the email addresses...

Comment: A temporary table would not have helped you anyway - you would have needed a permanent table, entirely replacing the excel sheet. Otherwise, you would have lost any speed gain again on filling the temporary table... Who is the owner of the database? Could he create such an additional table for you and grant the right to modify it? Then creating indices over both email_address columns might further increase performance (if you do not get the second table, the index over the first would probably already help, too).

Comment: Okay, no issues.. I just have to do this once. I will verify and accept your answer. Thank you very much.. :-)

Comment: I played in thoughts using patterns and unions (`WHERE email_address NOT LIKE '...' UNION WHERE email_address LIKE '...' AND '...'`), possibly involving the email domains. Idea: select all domains you have not in the list, and for each domain in the list, select those that are not given. I don't think, however, that this will run faster in the end - possibly even slower... Have no other idea so far, however.

Comment: The like operator can cause wrong information given it also accepts substrings of the string to be checked as well.

Comment: It won't give you wrong information if you design it appropriately. E. g. if you write `LIKE '%@mydomain.com' you get any address hosted at mydomain.com and no other one. If you had a domain 'mydomain.coming', it would not match. Problem is that for my idea working, you would have to create so many subqueries that I cannot imagine to get any performance gain any more...

Comment: Okay, can you just tell me how I can move the strings, the email-addresses which I am providing in a static manner into a new table? I have an empty table created. Thank you.

Comment: `INSERT INTO new_table (id, email_address, other_value) VALUES (1, 'email1', 'xyz'), (2, 'email2', 'zxy'), (3, 'email3', 'yzx')

Comment: Sorry, IT is blocking the chat. Will be home in two hours, let's meet then.

Comment: This worked, it was slow, but it's done. Thank you. :-)